# Laravel : Reaching nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Knowing the structure below, can I add a function to the `Container` class to get `records` directly with `Container::with('records')->get()` instead of `Container::with('boxes.letter.records')->get()` ?

> containers `hasMany` boxes `hasOne` letter `hasMany` records

```
class Container extends Model
{
    public function boxes(): hasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Box::class);
    }
    public function letters(): hasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Letter::class, Box::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Box extends Model
{
    public function letter(): hasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Letter::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Letter extends Model
{
    public function records(): hasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Record::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution # 1 ([`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) with joins)

Yes, you can access the records of a 3rd table directly through the use of [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), however need use `joins` to will can connect more tables.

```php
class Container extends Model
{
    public function records(): hasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Box::class, Letter::class)
                    ->join('records', 'letters.id', '=', 'records.letter_id')
                    ->select('records.*');
    }
}
```

### Solution # 2 ([`hasManyDeep`](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) by package)

Package: [staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

However, this allows you to quickly handle this multi-table relationship. With [`hasManyDeep`](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep), you can define complex relationships across multiple tables with ease.

```php
class Container extends Model
{
    public function records(): hasManyDeep
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Record::class, [Box::class, Letter::class]);
    }
}
```

[About hasManyDeep from Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/hasmanydeep-package)